# Logging data anonymously with log4net

Tags: c#, logging, vsto, log4net

I would like to log usage data of a VSTO-Application in a Database. everything works fine so far. now I want to have the logged data in an anomynous for UserName and HostName way using the log4net framework

Up to now I can write logged data to the database but it is not anonymously. I use this piece of config:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO [mytool].[Log] ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception], [UserName], [HostName]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @UserName, @HostName)" />
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@UserName"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="20"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:UserName}"/>
        </layout>
    </parameter>

    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@HostName"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="30"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}"/>
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    [...]
</appender>
```

My expected result is a md5 hash or some other hash for user and host stored in the database.

Comment: Can't you just omit Username and Hostname? or do you need it?

Comment: actually, I need it as I would like to have statistics how many different users there are

Comment: Can you change your commandText to include : `hashbytes('SHA1',@HostName)` instead of just @HostName

Comment: Thank you thomas-n your comment gave a good hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55357944/logging-data-anonymously-with-log4net#comment97441014_55357944